# Why does python throw a "true_divide" TypeError when using "/=" assignment on NumPy arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I get TypeError when using `/=` on a NumPy array right after creation:

```py
>>> arr = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> arr /= 2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-89-ff91ab204368> in <module>
----> 1 arr /= 2

TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting
was found for ufunc true_divide
```

But I can do:

```
>>> arr = arr / 2
>>> arr
array([0.5, 1, 1.5])
```

What's weirder, is that *after* doing the above I can do:

```
>>> arr /= 2
>>> arr
array([0.25, 0.5, 0.75])
```

What is happening?

Comment: Hint: check the dtype of the array before and after using float division.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other answer already mentioned issue is due to `dtype`. Let's go through the code and try to understand the issue. 
`NOTE: id() gives unique identify of object`
When you created the array

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> id(arr) # Hash address of array
139866867761280
>>> arr.dtype # dtype of array
dtype('int64')
```

As you can see type of array is `int64`. When you try to divide it by `2` it tried to write it back in same `ndarray` which is of type `int64` where as result is `float64` and hence the error

```
>>> arr /= 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc true_divide
```

Now when you do

```
>>> arr = arr / 2
>>> id(arr)
139866844116592
>>> arr.dtype
dtype('float64')
```

Notice How address is changes from previous operation and type is changed. Because address is changed and new `ndarray` is created hence no error. 
Now when you try `arr /= 2`

```
>>> arr /= 2
>>> arr
array([0.25, 0.5 , 0.75])
>>> arr.dtype
dtype('float64')
>>> id(arr)
139866844116592
```

Cause `dtype` was already `float64` we were able to perform the operation. Notice how the address remains the same. it's in place operation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I didn't know about the useful `id` function. It seems that this is true not just for numpy arrays, but python lists as well - probably any mutable object that supports the operation. The id changes when using `arr = arr + 2`, but not when using `arr += 2`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is because your array is an integer array.  When you do `/=`, it tries to do true division and put the values in-place back into the original array, but it can't because the new values are floats and the array has an integer dtype.  But when you use `/`, it makes a *new* array with a float dtype, which you then assign to the original name, and this float array supports `/=`.

Comment: Oops, yep, thinko, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! You are right about in-place modifications, and using id's as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69999729/5849847) seems to prove it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that ([1, 2, 3]) is type int64 and if their is a float in the array than the type is float64. If you want to know which type your array is therefore you can use the '.dtype'. You can define this int64 array to a float64 array.